# Imitating the look and feel of Visual Studio 2012

Tags: wpf, user-interface, tabs, docking

I know this is a very open ended question, so bear with me - is there any good way to imitate the look and feel of Visual Studio 2012's [interface](http://blog.nuclex-games.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/visual-studio-2012-rc.png)? I would very much like to emulate teh drag/drop capabilities and just the overall cleanliness of design.

So far I know about [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/), [WPFMDI](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/), SyncFusion's [approach](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/wpf/tools), and Infragistic's [Dock Manager](http://www.infragistics.com/products/wpf/dock-manager/). Infragistic's approach looks much like what I would like to have, but 1) I have no idea if I can use them in my [current project](https://github.com/vermiculus/automata) (licensing, etc.) and 2) I'd like to know (at least on a highish level) on how they actually *work*. Can anyone shed some light on how they would approach this?

I'll post my train of thought as an answer for starters.

---

**Visual Studio's interface (2012)**
[image: VS2012 Interface]

**AvalonDock 2.0**
[image: AvalonDock 2.0]

**WPFMDI** (kinda ugly)
[image: WPF MDI]

**SyncFusion's Dock Manager** (very much *not* open-source)
[image: SyncFusion's Dock Manager]

And lastly **Infragistic's Docking Manager** (also commercial)
[image: Infragistic's]

---

Again, VS2012 imitation is the goal - these are just a bunch of projects that have already attempted to complete this goal in the general.

Comment: Actipro Software also makes a good docking library that I use

Comment: Also very much not open-source :/ thanks though

Comment: if AvalonDock is open source, what's the problem wit it?

Comment: I'm not sure if new BSD is reducible to CC-BY-NC-SA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my silly logic, each tabbed interface should actually *be* a tab.

When the user clicks and drags the tab to the primary orientation (left/right for horizontal tabs, top/bottom for verticals), the tabs should change their ordering to accommodate and the view should stay the same.

However, if the tab is dragged perpendicular to its primary orientation, then a snapshot should be made of the tab, it should shrink to about 60% of its original size, and should be desaturated/made translucent. As the user drags it around, the image should obviously follow.

When the user mouse enters the center region of a `TabContainer` (subclass of Canvas? Page? I dunno), the little overlay pops up for easy docking.

If the user drags it to a `TabBar`, it adds itself to the appropriate spot on that `TabBar` (according to where the mouse is, etc.). Every `TabContainer` has exactly one `TabBar`.

What I can't figure out in this design is how you can grad a tab and have it fixed/floating/autohiding/etc. as what happens in VS.